# Stationarity in an ADL model

Tags: time-series, stationarity, lags, ardl

In an ADL model, in order to be consistent  do we require both the IV and DV to be stationary? 
In particular in a process of the form: $$\Phi(L)y_t=\Theta(L)x_t+\epsilon_t$$ 
where $\Phi(L)$ and $\Theta(L)$ are lag polinomials, do they both have to have roots outside the unit circle or is $\Phi(L)$ having unit roots outside the unit circle a sufficient condition for consistency of OLS estimation?

Comment: Hi Lorenzo. Yes. See section 6 at this link. They usually refer to the $x$ condition as stationarity  since roots usually refer to the response. But stationarity and root restrictions I think are equivalent. Also,  I always forget but I think, depending on notation, roots for $x$ might need to be inside unit circle.   https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/fa3a/de84b71d524b7d4b5cda6267665ac28225d4.pdf